# How to create relative xpath for check-box element?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I need to create xpath for the check box.It is a angular js element.I tried to produce xpath with firebug.But it is giving html xpath and its not useful.I would like to know how to create relative xpath for the checkbox which has angular js contents.

Following is my check box html content.Guide me how can I create relative xpath in multiple ways using the following code.

```
    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6">
<check-box class="ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" text="By post" name="post" ng-model="vm.options.byPost" tab-index="1" style="">
<div class="MMM-check-box" ng-class="customClass ? customClass : ''">
<div class="MMM-label ng-binding MMM-label--hidden" ng-class="!label ? 'MMM-label--hidden' : ''" style=""/>
<div class="MMM-check-box__field" ng-keydown="onFocus($event)" tabindex="1">
<a class="MMM-check-box__link" name="post" ng-click="change()" ng-class="toggle === true ? 'MMM-check-box__link--selected' : ''">
<svg id="Layer_1" class="MMM-toggle__icon" xml:space="preserve" style="enable-background:new 0 0 51.9 41.9;" viewBox="0 0 51.9 41.9" y="0px" x="0px" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
</a>
<div class="MMM-check-box__title ng-binding">By post</div>
<div class="MMM-check-box__textarea-container ng-hide" ng-show="withTextarea && toggle === true" style="">
</div>
</div>
</check-box>
</div>
```

Comment: @guy It is angular js component .So when I use  `id=Layer_1` ,it is identofying other checkbox at the top.It is not selecting my particular xpath.In my case `id=Layer_1` , under this id we have some 5 check boxes.So when I use _id_ it is identifying first checkbox and not identifying 5th check box.

Comment: You can put all the check boxes in list and select by index.

Comment: @guy No hope.Could you please help to create relative xpath for the above code? using..contains or stared-with or something else

Comment: What differentiates this combo box from the other 4? Can you add their html?

Comment: no one is going to mention that the "checkbox" is not even a checkbox, according to the html posted, but rather an svg?  @ManojSoundarrajan    if you could give us more html to go with, that would help a lot.  Just giving us a single html element is not useful when constructing xpath.

Comment: XPATH queries are represented as a path through the DOM that selects the particular node or nodes that you are interested in. Giving us a single HTML element and asking us to create an xpath query that selects it is like asking 'can you tell me how to get to Sesame st?'. No, because I don't know which country, city and suburb we are currently in. You must include the entire document if you want us to create an xpath query that will select that particular element.

Also, you mentioned there are other things with the same id? In that case you're using id wrong. Should be a class.

Comment: Ok, that's easier to work with. Now can you tell us see exactly which data you wish to extract from that <svg> tag?

Comment: @JamesScottTayler Yes. I need to identify the element which is located in the <svg> tag.

Comment: @JamesScottTayler Hi..Do you have any update on this?

Answer (score 1):

Try Below:-

```
//svg[@id='Layer_1']
```

Hope it will help you :)